# How can I display the value of which ever cell is current in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I display the value of whichever cell is current in another cell?

- I have a list of forty different numbers displayed in cells `D1:H8`.
- When I move the cursor to `D2` I want to display the value of that cell in cell `A1`.
- If I use the arrow keys to move the cursor to let's say `G6`, I want the value in `G6` to display in `A1`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to display the value of any of the cells in the range `D1:H8` in cell `A1` **without keying them in**; only by taking the cursor to one of the cells in the range

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate. If required show us the data and explain

Answer (score 1):

You will need code

The sample here puts the value of the first cell in a selection to A1

[image]

1. Right click your sheet tab
2. *View Code*
3. Paste in the code below

*code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Target.Cells(1)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then [a1].Value = rng1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, that works exactly as I needed.